# String width measurement method not accurate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, string

I am trying to size my RichTextBox.PageWidth to limit to 60 chars a line (fixed width font).  Basically I measure the string and then I set the PageWidth to the measured amount.

When I use it, my measurements are off by 2 chars.  (The last 2 chars wrap to the next line.)

Anyone have any idea on how I can get the width of a string for my RichTextBox WITHOUT actually putting that text in the RichTextBox

**String measure method** (taken from [here](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/glyphrun-and-so-forth/)):

```
private static double GetStringWidth(string text, 
                                     FontFamily fontFamily, 
                                     double fontSize)
{
    Typeface typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, 
                                     FontStyles.Normal, 
                                     FontWeights.Normal, 
                                     FontStretches.Normal);

    GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface;
    if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No glyph typeface found");

    double size = fontSize;

    ushort[] glyphIndexes = new ushort[text.Length];
    double[] advanceWidths = new double[text.Length];

    double totalWidth = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
    {
        ushort glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[n]];
        glyphIndexes[n] = glyphIndex;

        double width = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * size;
        advanceWidths[n] = width;

        totalWidth += width;
    }

    return totalWidth;
}
```

**Use of the above method:**

```
var strToMeasure="012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
richTextBox.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New");
var fontFamily = richTextBox.FontFamily;
var fontSize = richTextBox.FontSize;

var measuredWidth = GetStringWidth(strToMeasure, fontFamily, fontSize);

richTextBox.Document.PageWidth = measuredWidth;
richTextBox.Document.MaxPageWidth = measuredWidth;
richTextBox.Document.MinPageWidth = measuredWidth;
```

**UPDATE:**
Further testing has revealed that it is off by 2 chars all the time (for 4 char or for 100 chars).  This leads me to believe that the RichTextBox is padding something.

Comment: Can't you just use TextRenderer.MeasureText?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but unless you are using a fixed width font like Courier, the width of 60 characters is dependent on what those characters are. Using numbers as a proxy can only give an estimate. "If it is in" will typically take up less horizontal space than "wow wowona".

Comment: @reedparkes - Yes I could.  But I would rather not load that DLL (It is a "WinForms" dll and this is WPF App).

Comment: @hatchet - I updated my question to indicate that this is using a fixed width font.

Comment: Sorry @Vaccano, I totally missed that.

Comment: could this be the problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569191/setting-wpf-richtextbox-width-and-height-according-to-the-size-of-a-monospace-fo

Comment: @hatchet - Thanks for pointing me to that.  It looks helpful, but it is failing because some of the values are NaN (Auto).  (I am still looking into it.)

Comment: @hatchet - that was it!  Thank you for the pointer.  Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that RichTextBox is consuming some of its horizontal width for its own layout purposes, causing your calculation to always come up a little short. This stackOverflow question has an answer that should help you solve your issue.

[Setting WPF RichTextBox width and height according to the size of a monospace font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569191/setting-wpf-richtextbox-width-and-height-according-to-the-size-of-a-monospace-fo)

Answer (score 1):

I use this method, its probably not the best but its very acurate.

```
    private double MeasureText(string text, FontFamily font, double fontsize)
    {
        var mesureLabel = new TextBlock(); 
        mesureLabel.FontFamily = font;
        mesureLabel.FontSize = fontsize; 
        mesureLabel.Text = text; 
        mesureLabel.Padding = new Thickness(0); 
        mesureLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0); 
        mesureLabel.Width = double.NaN; 
        mesureLabel.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity)); 
        mesureLabel.Arrange(new Rect(mesureLabel.DesiredSize));
        return mesureLabel.ActualWidth;
    }
```

Usage:

```
 double length = MeasureText("hello", FontFamily, FontSize);
```